# Gnuplot missing points and xtics in plot with Year-month xrange

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having a problem plotting a particular chart on Gnuplot 5.4. Here is the data (assumed to be in file test.csv)

```
report_date,contract_area,emerg_tally,mean_response_time,median_response_time,percentile_80_response_time
2022-03,10,1,1.133333,1.133333,1.133333
2022-04,10,12,33.013888,4.6166665,27.0133328
2022-05,10,20,3.608333,3.175,4.473333
2022-06,10,21,6.703174,2.533333,4.7
2022-07,10,2,2.766666,2.7666665,3.1966664


2022-04,11,14,19.255951,3.6749995,15.8433328
2022-05,11,8,5.789583,3.05,3.993333
2022-06,11,17,75.061764,2.083333,3.3199996
2022-07,11,11,3.15606,2.583333,3.8


2022-04,12,9,35.253703,4.816666,8.373333
2022-05,12,14,3.140475,2.458333,3.3233332
2022-06,12,14,9.305952,2.8999995,7.8299998
2022-07,12,4,5.508333,2.708333,7.5399998


2022-03,13,1,0.9,0.9,0.9
2022-04,13,4,2.583333,2.7249995,3.1533328
2022-05,13,22,4.797726,2.6499995,6.1233328
2022-06,13,21,7.394444,2.5,4.966666
2022-07,13,1,2.85,2.85,2.85
```

The first column is a timestamp (Year-month).

The plot script is as follows:

```
set datafile separator comma
set datafile columnheaders

set timefmt '%Y-%m'
set xdata time
set format x '%Y-%m'
set xlabel 'Job completion Date'
set ylabel 'Median completion time'

set xrange ['2022-04':*]
set xtics '2022-04', '2022-05' '2022-06', '2022-07'

plot "./test.csv"  index 0 using 1:5 title "Area 10" with lines lc 1, \
     ''            index 1 using 1:5 title "Area 11" with lines lc 2, \
     ''            index 2 using 1:5 title "Area 12" with lines lc 3, \
     ''            index 3 using 1:5 title "Area 13" with lines lc 4
```

[image: Output image]

This is not what I am expecting:

- The 2nd and 3rd data series are missing an initial point (for 2022-04). It could be that all series are missing there initial data point, but that this is masked by the range starting at 2022-04 (series 1 and 4 have a 2022-03 data point).
- The x-axis is only showing a tic mark for 2022-06. I would expect a 2022-05 tic mark (as 2022-04 and 2022-07 will be at the left and right boundaries respectively).

I have a set of similar scripts which differ only in the date format (`'%Y-%m-%d'` rather than `'%y-%m'`).

Does anyone have any idea how to correct these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Missing points** - The program interprets the command `set datafile columnheaders` to mean that the first line of each data set in the file will consist of column headers.  That's not what you want, since in your file only the first data set has a separate line of headers. Instead you can use the `skip` keyword in the plot command to ignore lines at the start of the file (see below)

**Unexpected lack of x-axis ticmarks** - gnuplot has always been bad at auto-selection of tic intervals along a time axis with dates.  There are some improvements in the development version but I'd say it has only reached the level of 'not quite as bad'.  You can fix this by giving an explicit tic interval of one month = (~2592000 seconds).  Obviously that is not quite correct because some months have 31 days, but for sparse time points like the ones you have it is close enough.

**Modified script**

```
set datafile separator comma
set datafile nocolumnheaders    # only the 1st data set has headers

set timefmt '%Y-%m'
set xdata time
set format x '%Y-%m'
set xlabel 'Job completion Date'
set ylabel 'Median completion time'

set xrange ['2022-04':*] noextend
set xtics 2592000     # 3600 * 24 * 30 ~= seconds per month

plot "./test.csv" skip 1 index 0 using 1:5 title "Area 10" with lines lc 1, \
     ''            index 1 using 1:5 title "Area 11" with lines lc 2, \
     ''            index 2 using 1:5 title "Area 12" with lines lc 3, \
     ''            index 3 using 1:5 title "Area 13" with lines lc 4
```

[image]

Or you could specify individual tic marks along x.  Your script attempted that but the syntax was missing parentheses and a comma.  You could use:

```
set xtics ('2022-04', '2022-05', '2022-06', '2022-07')
```